# Debug Struts Action Classes

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, struts

My application runs on a remote server.

I use tomcat to deploy the web based part of my application.

The flow is Action classes calls the remote classes using RMI.

I am using Eclipse and When I browse a page, am able to debug the remote java classess, But I need to debug Action classes also as it also contains more logic.

How will I do it, Please help, Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sridevi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either launch Tomcat in debug mode from Eclipse, or launch tomcat with remote debug options, and attach a remote debug session from Eclipse to this tomcat server (in a similar way as you're probably doing for the remote RMI server).

See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_debug_a_Tomcat_application.3F for how to start tomcat in remote debug mode:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=1044
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
catalina jpda start
```